# (intermediate value).on is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have tried to understand this error, specifically missing semicolons and closing parentheses but can't see and understand the issue.

Any ideas why I get `(intermediate value).on is not a function`?

I am trying to async call a function (broken link checker) and get the result when it is done analyzing the entire page for the broken links.

```js
const { SiteChecker } = require('broken-link-checker');

const options = {
  cacheResponses: false,
  filterLevel: 2
};

const launchSiteChecker = (address, options) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const siteChecker = new SiteChecker(options)
      .on('error', (error) => {
        return reject({
          error: true,
          message: error
        })
      })
      .on('link', (result, customData) => {
        return resolve({
          success: true,
          result: result,
          customData: customData
        });
      });

    siteChecker.enqueue(address);
  });
};

module.exports = {
  runAudits: async function(address) {
    const auditResults = await launchSiteChecker(address, options)
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        return result;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
      });

    return JSON.stringify(auditResults);
  }
}
```

I am using https://github.com/stevenvachon/broken-link-checker

Comment: The error means that your `SiteChecker` object does not have a method called "on".

Comment: If you're using this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/broken-link-checker the documentation is pretty clear on how you attach handlers...

Comment: Your code looks like the documentation example of https://github.com/stevenvachon/broken-link-checker, did you checked your node version is >= 12.x?

Comment: Thank you. I have node v12.18.0. I am using https://github.com/stevenvachon/broken-link-checker and as mentioned in the readme file, they do have the `on` method. So confused here (I am a newbie)